# Can someone help me an AutoHotKey script?

Tags: autohotkey

I've read the help and guide for it but I just can't figure it out. All I want to do is create a hotkey that when pressed will move my mouse until the hotkey is pressed again. Can anyone tell me how to do this? It should be really simple but apparently I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you gotten anything working? Can you show your script so far?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but I could imagine that you want to prevent your screensaver from activating through this script. If so then I would recommend to only move your mouse 1 pixel up and down again every minute or so based on a timer, which you can turn on/off. If this is what you want I can provide a script.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much the most annoying HotKey ever, but here you go (hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>);

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 3
^!c::
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 1
if DoMouseMove
{
   DoMouseMove := false
   return
}

DoMouseMove := true
Loop
{
   Sleep 100
   Random, randX, 1, 1028
   Random, randY, 1, 800
   MouseMove, randX, randY, 25
   Sleep, 100

   if not DoMouseMove 
      break
}
DoMouseMove := false
return
```

Answer (score 0):

I will throw in my solution.

```
pause::
If (Toggle := !Toggle) ; Toggle the value True/False
    {
        ToolTip Mouse Mover,A_ScreenWidth/2,0 ; Show that Mouse Mover is active
        SetTimer MoveMouse, 1000 ; 1000 ms = 1 sec. Every minute (60000 ms) is probably enough.
    }
Else
    {
        Tooltip ;  Turn Mouse Mover alert window off
        SetTimer MoveMouse, Off ; Turn the timer off
    }
return

MoveMouse:
    MouseMove, 1, 0, 1, R ;Move the mouse one pixel to the right
    Sleep, 50 ; Wait 50 ms. Not realy required, but makes the move visible
    MouseMove, -1, 0, 1, R ;Move the mouse back one pixel
return
```